# Angular Lazy Loading Submodule

Tags: angular

I have an application which uses lazy loading in multiple levels. The initial path of '/' is caught in the main app.routes and redirected to a lazy loaded module. That module also has its own submodule-1.routes and is just a container for other feature modules.  In the submodule-1.routes, I am lazy loading the feature module.  From what I can tell it seems that the modules are not being lazy loaded.

I have tried to create the routes in submodule-1 itself, and lazy load the feature modules from there but that hasnt helped.

Below is the folder structure

```
app
app.module.ts
app.routing-module.ts
-modules
--login
---login.module.ts
---login-routing.module.ts
---pages
----login-user
-----login-user.module.ts(LoginUserPageModule)
-----login-user-page.ts(LoginUserPage)
--signup
---signup.module.ts
---signup-routing.module.ts
----pages
-----signup-email
------signup-email.module.ts(SignUpEmailPageModule)
------signup-email-page.ts(SignUpEmailPage)
```

Below is my main routes in app.routes.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'signup-email', loadChildren: './modules/signup/signup.module#SignupModule' },
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './modules/login/login.module#LoginModule' },

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Signup Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SignupRoutingModule } from './signup-routing.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SignupRoutingModule
  ],
  exports:[]
})
export class SignupModule { }
```

SignupRoutes.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const SIGNUP_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './pages/signup-email/signup-email.module#SignupEmailPageModule'
    }
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(SIGNUP_ROUTES)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SignupRoutingModule { }
```

SignupEmailPageModule

```
import { SignupEmailPage } from './signup-email.page';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SignupEmailPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule
    ,RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [SignupEmailPage]
})
export class SignupEmailPageModule {}
```

Login Module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    LoginRoutingModule
  ],
  providers:[
  ]
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

LoginRoutes

```
export const LOGIN_ROUTES: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './pages/login-user/login-user.module#LoginUserPageModule'
    }
];


@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(LOGIN_ROUTES)
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LoginRoutingModule { }
```

LoginUserPageModule

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginUserPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
    SharedModule
  ],
  declarations: [LoginUserPage]
})
export class LoginUserPageModule {}
```

Since the default path of '/' is being directed to login which is working, i expect the signup module to be lazy loaded, and visible only once. However, below is the image that i see from Augury on the initial load of the application which makes it seem like both LoginModule and SignupEmailModule are being loaded multiple times and not lazy loaded at all. As a result, I see the LoginUserPage and SignupEmailPage already loaded as in the image below from Augury.

[image: Augury Representation showing the modules/pages already loaded]

After removing the the `{ preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }` from app.routing.ts. I do see that the modules are now loaded lazily, however, when I access each of the lazy loaded modules, I see an extra 'lazy' node in the Augury graph as below. I'm not sure why that is, and if it should be there ?

Also, whenever a lazyloaded route is loaded, the other route goes back to showing as lazy, should it not just stay loaded from that point on ? Why does it go back to showing as 'lazy' in the graph, almost as if it hasnt been loaded.

Augury graph after accessing the default path which is also lazy loaded
[image: Image after access the default path which is also lazy loaded]

Augury graph after accessing the lazy loaded route of 'signup' page
[image: Image after accessing the lazy loaded route of 'signup-email']

Comment: you have { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules }, hence no lazy loading

Comment: Wow, I cant believe I missed that. Thanks it is now working, but one thing which is strang, and i'm not sure if i can upload another image. Now, I see the login module loaded, and for signup it says (lazy) as in the picture above. However, the login module graphs is still as above. I'm not sure why that middle node of 'lazy' is there ? When I load the signup page, it also looks like the image above with a middle node that only says 'lazy', im not sure where that is coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `app.routes.ts` you set `preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules`, this means your modules are being preloaded. So instead of loading your modules when they are first requested (lazily), the modules get loaded asynchronously in the background. It's kind of an in between strategy between eager and lazy loading but it means that all your modules get loaded in the end. From the [documentation:](https://angular.io/guide/router#preloading-background-loading-of-feature-areas)

> After each successful navigation, the router looks in its configuration for an unloaded module that it can preload. Whether it preloads a module, and which modules it preloads, depends upon the preload strategy.
>
> The Router offers two preloading strategies out of the box:
>
> - No preloading at all which is the default. Lazy loaded feature areas are still loaded on demand.
> - Preloading of all lazy loaded feature areas.

Comment: I have gotten that to work now, but can you explain why after the module is actually accessed, I have that middle 'lazy' node still showing in my graph still ?

Comment: You lazy load a module inside a lazy loaded module. That's why there are two nodes there. I am not quite sure, but I think the fact that it has no name to it comes from the fact that you point to the pages with an empty route (`''`). Augury attaches the route name to each node, and there is only an empty string in both cases.

Comment: ok that makes sense, but do you know why once i load the lazy loaded login module as in the picture above, the signup module is showing 'lazy', and the loaded module is showing as loaded. But then when i switch from login module which is the current lazy loaded module, to signup, signup is now showing as loaded which is correct, but now login module is showing as 'lazy'.  Shouldnt the login module be showing as loaded since its been loaded once already, or do lazy loaded modules always get offloaded and are showing as loaded only when in use ?

Comment: I currently use Angular 8.2.0 and I do not experience such behaviour. Lazily loaded modules stay loaded (would be inefficient if they didn't). As per https://augury.rangle.io/pages/guides/routes.html, the lazily loaded Components should be displayed after loading. Are you sure you do not do a page reload when switching from one route to the other? If this happens, all lazily loaded modules are "unloaded" again. E. g. if you enter the route for your signup route in the browsers url field, then the app gets reloaded. Which version of Augury are you using?

Comment: Thats exactly what I was doing for testing purposes, since I have not yet implemented any routes to go back, through the app but only forward, i was entering it directly in the url field. When i move forward through the app using actual routing, everything looks fine. Thanks for your advice.